# awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

Ok I'm getting this error `awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception error`. When I try to remove a `JPanel`.

Whats confusing me is when I remove another `JPanel` it works perfectly fine but this one it doesn't. The first Code below shows the `JPanel` that when I click on a `JButton` it doesn't remove the `JPanel`.

```
public class buttontime implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime) {
        Price priceObject = new Price();
        priceObject.getPricepanel();
        remove(priceObject.getPricepanel());
        priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();

        add(timeObject.getTimePanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();


    }
}

//This one gives me 0 errors.
public class buttonprice implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ClickPrice) {


        Price priceObject = new Price();
        priceObject.SelectPrice();
        remove(timeObject.getTimePanel());
        timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();

        add(priceObject.getPricepanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
remove(priceObject.getPricepanel());
```

If you are getting a `NullPointerException` only when removing this panel, `priceObject.getPricepanel()` must be returning `null`.

Comment: How comes when i add priceObject.getPricepanel()  it works but when i remove it, i get that error how can i overcome this error completely baffled me

Comment: @user2188332 maybe after you added it it because null

Comment: Sounds more like `timeObject` is null

Comment: @MadProgrammer But he said the one with `timeObject` is working

Comment: can i send someone my code because im really confused been trying to solve this for an hour

Comment: @Doorknob I don't see where `timeObject` is created, in fact, the OP is creating local objects of the `priceObject`.  There is simply not enough code to go on

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I agree with that. The problem is most likely elsewhere. This question is also most likely Too Localized

Comment: @user2188332 Don't send your code, create a simple example of the problem and post it.

Comment: private JButton timeButton;
                 private JButton priceButton;

Comment: @user2188332 _can i send someone my code because im really confused_ - the someone would be the consultant you are paying ;-) Or in other words: this site is for helping _you_ to to solve the problems _yourself_ If you don't understand the answers, you need to take a step back and fresh up/learn the some basics (on Swing, on Java, on programming in general ...) Oh, and don't forget to follow the references given and _read_ them (usually it shows when you didn't :-)